# How to show progress bar or any other animation when call window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `window.open()` like

```
var courseId = $courseId;
var exportURL = "scormExport.do?courseId="+ $courseId + "&exportPlayer=true&exportAssets=true&exportJson=true";
window.open( exportURL, "LS3R60 SCORM Course Export",
    "width=1024, height=768, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, resizable=yes, 
     directories=no, status=yes, menubar=no");
```

The problem is as URL is calling on server. And when window open then it takes lot of time to load the stuff and then showing it on new window. So i want that when i call `window.open()`, then i can show some kind of animation stuff like progress bar, or any other overlay or anything that show that some thing is in progressing.

How can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not display the progress bar or [animation here] by default on your target page, and when you have all your resources loaded, hide that animation? You can use a loading gif as your animation, and when all resources load, set `display:none` to it.